# How to avoid quadratic time in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, networkx

I've created a graph G with NetworkX, where my nodes are movies and actors, and there's an edge if an actor partecipated in a movie. I have a dictionary for all actors and all movies. I want to find the pair of movies that share the largest number of actors.

I thought that the solution could be something like that:

```
    maximum=0        
    pair=[]
    dict_pair_movies={}            
    for actor in actors:
        list_movies=list(nx.all_neighbors(G, actor))
        for movie1 in list_movies:
            for movie2 in list_movies:
                if movie1!=movie2:
                    dict_coppia_movies[(movies1,movies2)]+=1                 
                    if dict_coppia_movies[(movies1,movies2)]>massimo:
                        maximum=dict_coppia_movies[(movies1,movies2)]
                        pair=[movies1,movies2]
    return pair
```

But this can't really work because there are 2 millions of actors.
I tried if the code could work in a smaller case, but I ran in two problems:

1. This line `dict_coppia_movies[(movies1,movies2)]+=1` doesn't work; But I could get the result that I wanted with this one `dict_coppia_movies[(movies1,movies2)]=dict_coppia_movies.get((movies1,movies2),0) + 1`
2. I don't know ho to specify that, if I have two film A and B, the combination "A,B" it's the same of "B,A".
   Instead the algorithm creates two different keys.

I even tried something with `nx.common_neighbors` that should gives me the number of actors of two movies, but the problems were always the quadratic time and my inability to tell the algorithm to iterate only for different movies.

EDIT: Maybe I've found the solution, but I can't check if it's the right one. I thought that the wise road to follow should be with `nx.common_neighbors` so I could just iterate for two nodes. In order to make the algorithm fast enough, I tried to use the `zip` function with the `list` of movies and the `set` of movies.

```
movieList=list(movies.keys())
movieSet=set(movieLista)   
     
def question3():
    maximum=0
    pair=[]
    for node1,node2 in zip(movies,movieSet):
        neighborsList=(list(nx.common_neighbors(G,node1,node2)))
        if len(neighborsList)>maximum:
            maximum=len(neighborsList)
            pair=[node1,node2]
    
    return pair
```

This algorithm gives me a result, but I can't really check if it's correct. I knew that the `zip` function in the case of two list or set with different lenght it will truncate to the shortest one, but in this case `movies` and `movieSet` have the same lenght so it should work...

Comment: Let's say you have for each movie a set of all actors in that movie. Then by computing the intersection of any two sets would give you the set (and count) of actors that appeared in both movies. But you would still have to compute the intersection for every pair of movies, which takes quadratic time. I am not saying there is nothing that solves your problem in O(n) time, but I am unable to come up with one. If somebody does have a method, *bravo* and I would be very interested to know what that was.

Comment: @Booboo - I think you're right, but what you're describing is much faster than the code above (and a note for OP - the current code looks at each pair of movies a single individual is in twice, rather than just once).  You'll be much better off creating a set for each movie and then comparing pairs.

Comment: You can get some efficiency if you order the movies by number of actors (large to small).  Take the first (largest) movie and compare its intersection with each successive movie.  Stop when the movies in the comparison have fewer actors than the biggest overlap found so far.  Then go back to the second movie in the list and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of what each variable you're working with means, I think that the following should work. This makes use of Joel's "movie size" heuristic.

Notably, the sorting process is O(n log(n)), so it has no impact on the overall O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity.

```
def question3():
    def comp_func(pair):
        return len(pair[1])
    
    movie_list = sorted([(k,set(d)) for k,d in G.adjacency() if k in movies], 
                        key = comp_func, reverse = True)
    maximum = 0
    pair = [None,None]
    for i,(movie_1,set_1) in enumerate(movie_list):
        if len(set_1) <= maximum:
            break
        for movie_2,set_2 in movie_list[i+1:]:
            if len(set_2) <= maximum:
                break
            m = len(set_1&set_2)
            if m > maximum:
                maximum = m
                pair[:] = movie_1,movie_2
    return pair
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I don't understand why the function take pair as input, I want to create a function that gives me that one pair of nodes who shares the largest number of actor.
Furthermore, if I try to run `movie_list`, it gives me the error `'method' object is not iterable`, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I missed some parentheses, should work now

Comment: The job of the `comp_func` function is to work within the `sorted` call; it just specifies how two pairs of the form `(movie_1,set_1)` should be compared when the array is sorted

Comment: I've edited my post so that the computation is done in the `question3()` function call instead of in the top-most environment

Comment: It works great. Thank you again, so in `sorted` we use `set(d)` because hashmaps are faster?

Comment: @johan14 In short, I suspect that calculating the intersection `set_1 & set_2` (starting from hashmaps corresponding to the sets of adjacent nodes) is faster than using `nx.common_neighbors` for each pair of nodes